# can't get ID after persisting and merging an entity using eclipselink

Tags: mysql, jpa, eclipselink

I'm using Glassfish 4.1.1 and EclipseLink 2.5.2 with MySQL in Netbeans 8.1 under Centos 7.

My entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "headCatalog")
@XmlRootElement
public class HeadCatalog implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "headCatalog")
@TableGenerator(name = "headCatalog", table = "sequenceNumbers",
        pkColumnName = "tableName", valueColumnName = "sequenceNumber",
        pkColumnValue = "headCatalog")
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "brand")
private String brand;
@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "model")
private String model;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "arc")
private double arc;
....
```

I'm trying to load data into it using:

```
headCatalog = new HeadCatalog();
headCatalogFacade.create(headCatalog);
headCatalog.setBrand(brand);
headCatalog.setModel(model);
headCatalog.setArc(arc);
headCatalogFacade.save(headCatalog);
headCatalogFacade.flush();
//headCatalogFacade.refresh(headCatalog);
headCatalogID = headCatalog.getId();
....
```

When I run this, headCatalogID comes back null (note, create calls em.persist and save calls em.merge; this is the boilerplate code that netbeans generates). I've set a break point and after the flush the ID value is in the database. If I un-comment the refresh I get a message saying that headCatalog is detached.

I'm using @TableGenerator as a work-around; if I use

```
@GeneratedValue (GenerationType.SEQUENCE or strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

I get:

```
Severe:   com.wjrust.sprinklere.entities.HeadCatalog.id may not be null
```

If I do a query and reload the entity then ID is there but since I don't know what the ID is, creating the query is a problem.

So, how does one get the ID after saving an entity?

Comment: take a look at `headCatalogFacade.save(headCatalog);` - it has a returnType of the object written to your database. Just write `headCatalog = headCatalogFacade.save(headCatalog);`. When u get it's ID, it won't be `null` anymore. You can implement your own `save()`-method to change that behaviour.

Comment: Thank you. headCatalogFacade.save(headCatalog) doesn't have that return type but the only thing that it does is call em.merge which does have that return. That's a bug in the netbeans boilerplate generator; it should propagate the return back up the call stack. 

If you resubmit this comment as an answer, I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `headCatalogFacade.save(headCatalog);` - it has a returnType of the object written to your database. Just write `headCatalog = headCatalogFacade.save(headCatalog);`. When u get it's ID, it won't be null anymore. You can implement your own save()-method to change that behaviour.

If your IDE autogenerated that method take a close look at what method it calls. `em.merge(Object object)` has a returnType of the object you pass as a parameter.

I always like to implement the basic methods to my EJB as follows:

```
public <T> T save(T o) {
    if (o == null) throw new EntityNotFoundException("Dao::save does not allow null values.");
    return em.merge(o);
}

public void remove(Object o) {
    if (o == null) throw new EntityNotFoundException("Dao::remove does not allow null values.");

    em.remove(em.merge(o));
}

public <T> T find(Class<T> clazz, Object id) {
    return em.find(clazz, id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When JPA sets the ID on the entity passed to persist depends on your generation strategy and the provider.  Some strategies allow for preallocation, so the ID can be set on the persist call.  For the most part though,  you are only safe to assume it is set when after the transaction commits or the context is synchronized to the database (em.flush).  You did not show the transactional scope of your methods, so you may just need to call em.flush in your create method so that the entity passed in has its ID set before the headCatalogFacade.create method returns, so that it is consistently set when you plan to use it.

Merge returns a managed copy of what you pass in.  If what you pass in is a new entity, it will never have its ID set - only the managed entity will have its ID set when the context syncs (unless it can be preallocated).  If you are in the same context, the save call isn't even needed, as the first call to create/persist causes that instance to be managed - so the managed instance returned is the same instance you passed in anyway.  If merge is required, then it means you are serializing your entity to/from the headCatalogFacade, and so will need to return the entity back from each of your calls to be able to see the result - and I'm also guessing the database was showing a duplicate, unpopulated HeadCatalog row on each pass of this method.

For the Id may not be null message, you would need to show where exactly you are getting that message, and the headCatalogFacade code for it to be understood.